# Image tint Button Android Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to create a CustomRenderer for Android inherit to ButtonRenderer with an Image. I want change color of Image programmatically like `TintColor` on iOS.

For example, my CustomRenderer iOS :

```
public class IconButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var button = e.NewElement;
    }

    public override void Draw(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        // Here I change color of Image in Red.
        Control.ImageView.Image = Control.ImageView.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
        Control.ImageView.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
    }


}
```

On Android: 
`Control` is an `Android.Widget.Button` and not have Image property but `Xamarin.Forms.Button` has property Image and use `Android.Widget.Button` for Android.

How I can access image with format Android for change color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Image tint Button Android Xamarin Forms

[Orignal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jPTI.png)

## Solution 1 :

As @Mathias Kirkegaard said, in your `ButtonRenderer` you could use [SetColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) to change color :

```
Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```

It did work in native Android, but has some problem in `Xamarin.Forms`, it only changes the `Button` background color like this: [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrdbm.png). Hope someone could find a solution, and if I find a solution to solve this issue I will come back and update my answer.

## Solution 2 :

You could use the plugin : [Tinted Image](https://github.com/shrutinambiar/xamarin-forms-tinted-image) and add a click event to implement the same feature.

1. Install the `Plugin.CrossPlatformTintedImage` nuget package
2. Initialize the renderer in your iOS, Android, and UWP projects as shown below:

   ```
   Xamarin.Forms.Init();    
   TintedImageRenderer.Init();
   ```
3. In Xaml:

   ```
   <ContentPage 
       ...
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Plugin.CrossPlatformTintedImage.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.CrossPlatformTintedImage.Abstractions"
        ...>
        ...
        <controls:TintedImage x:Name="buttonImage" TintColor="Blue" Source="redDis.png"/>
   ...
   </ContentPage>
   ```
4. In code, [Adding a Tap Gesture Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/) :

   ```
   var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
   tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => 
   {
       // handle the tap
   };
   buttonImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
   ```

[Effect after adding a click event on Tinted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN0qg.png)

## Solution 3 :

If you need to use `ImageButton`, you could refer to this solution. I didn't test it but you could use the [ImageButton from XLab](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton).

- XLab [ImageButton](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ImageButton.cs) Source code
- XLab [ImageButtonRenderer](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Controls/ImageButton/ImageButtonRenderer.cs) Source code

Comment: Solution 1 is not my goal. Solution 3 : "This project is no longer maintained. It may not work with newer versions of Xamarin.Forms."
The solution 2 is the best but I try create a renderer with the `tapGestureRecognizer` because I need to use many times in solution.

Comment: @MatthieuLemonnier, you could set the `TapGestureRecognizer` in `Xaml` like [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/#Using_Xaml).

Comment: Thx, solution 2 is the answer.

Comment: @MatthieuLemonnier, happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

On a button you can use "SetColorFilter(color)"

You might be able to get the color using the ContextCompat:

`var color = new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(Context, Resource.Color.Green));`

and then apply it:

`yourButton.SetColorFilter(color)`

Not sure whether you need to use an ImageButton rather than a simple Button.

Comment: SetColorFilter() not found for button `Android.Widget.Button` maybe I need ImageButton but `Xamarin.Forms` not have a ImageButton.